# glossaries \gls prints too wide

Tags: margins, glossaries

I am using the glossaries package to define acronyms in my thesis report. When I use \gls{} command to print an acronym in the body of the text, the printed line exceeds the margin (too wide). Captions of figures, as well as some entries in the list of figures and table of contents are also breaching the wide margins of my document. I have searched a lot but no one else seems to have the same problem. Can anyone suggest. Below is the preamble of my file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
%%Packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy,toc,acronym,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{rrt}{RRT}{Rapidly Exploring Random Trees}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
 \vspace*{50\p@}%
 {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
 \hrule                                        % horizontal line
 \vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
 \interlinepenalty\@M
 \Huge \scshape \thechapter \space \scshape #1\par                         %
 % chapter title
 \vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
 \hrule                                        % horizontal rule
 \nobreak
 \vskip 40\p@
 }%
}
\makeatother
%%New Operators
\doublespacing
\begin{document}

 \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, 
 minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
 \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=1cm]
 \tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
 \tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\chapter{first chapter}
Using the glossaries package when I use the command \gls{rrt} it exceeds
the wide margins (which results in underfull badness warning as well)

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I am using Texlive with texlipse on ubuntu 14.04. I am pasting the image below[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have edited my question to add a mwe as well. @karlkoeller

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @karlkoeller , I have added an screenshot of the issue now to the question. The acronym is exceeding the right margin of my command.

Comment: I suspect you are using `latex` rather than `pdflatex`. See [The long form of acronyms won't break across a line](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#nolinebreak)

Comment: yes I am using latex+dvips+ps2pdf. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. As Nicola highlighted in the comment. The easier way is to use pdflatex but it can be done for latex as well by using the breaklinks option in the hyperref package

```
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
```

It works for me now. Thanks.

[image]